# How to add reCaptcha while doing comments on my drupal website

Tags: comments, captcha

I am developing a drupal website. To avoid spam I have decided to use [reCAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module while user registration and before putting comments on my website.

How to achieve this? Can I use reCaptcha while submitting comments?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, Its done. Procedure as follows :

I have downloaded 2 modules [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) & [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha).

Then extract them into **/var/www/site/modules/** .

Then I have restart my web server. Then goto browser.

Next I have found CAPTCHA and reCaptcha options on **modules** section.

Then I configured CAPTCHA settings in configuration section according to my requirement.

Thats it !!  When I try to do comment on my website it was given me captcha challenge This is what all i need.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: I don't think restart webserver is mandatory here.

Comment: What am I post in my answer. Is anything wrong. What I post that just download & install & configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Just download & install [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module.

Goto Configuration setting & configure it.

Or you can use these modules also. I think this may help you.

1. [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) : They kill 99% of spam.
2. [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom)

Comment: Samzha, are you sure OP can use this module for submitting comments? If yes please elaborate.

Comment: I think it'll work.

Comment: samzha OP already know about this module. If you are sure about this module then only post this as answer. right now your answer doesn't show any confirmation.

Comment: Ya this modules works.